# How to transform exceptions into result in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm using this function

```ml
(** Wraps an exception in result *)
let try_ (f : 'a -> 'b) (x : 'a) : ('b, exn) result =
  try
    Ok (f x)
  with 
    e -> Error e
```

I'm not very sure that this is safe, or if there is a better alternative in the stdlib. I'm using this in a project with Lwt, maybe promise rejection needs to be handled?

The motivation is that I'm using `Lwt_result.t` together with `let (let*) = Lwt_result.Infix.(>>=)`, exceptions do not fit well with `let*`

Comment: Sometimes, functions that raise exceptions have a result equivalent, which is better because IIRC `try/with` is not free, so wrapping every possible-raising exception functions might turn out to be expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @jthulhu, I'm not using this for every function call only for the ones that I know that raise exceptions. Yojson.Safe.from_string for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly typesafe, at least.

If you look at the type of [`Result.bind`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Result.html#VALbind):

```
val bind : ('a, 'e) result ->
       ('a -> ('b, 'e) result) -> ('b, 'e) result
```

Your result must always have an exception as the error. This may limit your design options as you build your program.

Comment: Can non-exception things be raised in OCaml? I didn't realized that, thanks!

Comment: @geckos no, only exceptions can be raised (look at the type of `raise` in an OCaml repl). But `('a, 'e) result` is not bound to what can be raised or not, it's just a regular sum type: `type ('a, 'e) result = Ok of 'a | Error of 'e`.

Answer (score 2):

A `catch-all` exception clause that captures an exception without reraising is a programming error in most cases.

Indeed, an exception might be raised to signal that the local computation context is invalid, and that the current computation should be scratched and restarted at a far away layer defined by the exception handler. Consider the worst case of an `Out_of_memory` exception for instance, in this case one really want to reach the exception handler that would free some memory before trying to do anything else. When you capture any exception even those you don't know anything about, you lose this information.

Contrarily catching a known exception is often fine because you know what is the meaning and context of the exception. For instance, translating a
`Not_found` exception in your code is generally fine

```ml
let to_opt f = match f with
| x -> Some x
| exception Not_found -> None
```

More generally, `exceptions` that signals local failure are fine to turn into a `result`. But it is much safer to write a specialized function that only converts exceptions with a known semantics.

Comment: I can reraise the exception after matching the result and dealing with the known exceptions

Comment: I didn't know that I can capture exceptions in a match branch, cool! I will take a second look in my code with that in mind, maybe try_ is redundant